# how to dock javaplot window to a JPanel in java

Tags: java, swing

I am using [Javaplot](http://javaplot.panayotis.com/doc/com/panayotis/gnuplot/JavaPlot.html) for plotting graph.

```
import com.panayotis.gnuplot.JavaPlot;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaPlot p = new JavaPlot();
        p.addPlot("sin(x)");
        p.plot();
    }
}
```

The above code plots sin(x) on a dedicated window. I have a custom **application window** in my java swing project. How do I dock the java plot output graph inside a **JPanel** in my application window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but it looks like you can wrap your `JavaPlot` in a [`JPlot`](http://javaplot.panayotis.com/doc/com/panayotis/gnuplot/swing/JPlot.html), a subclass of `JPanel`, and add the panel to your custom application window:

```
customApplicationWindow.add(new JPlot(p));
```

For [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422341/how-to-dock-javaplot-window-to-a-jpanel-in-java/30422465?noredirect=1#comment48931542_30422465), interposing a call to `JPlot#plot()` worked:

```
JPlot jplot = new JPlot(p);
jplot.plot();
customApplicationWindow.add(jplot);
```

Comment: Adding the following worked. JPlot jplot = new JPlot(p); jplot.plot(); customApplicationWindow.add(jplot);